# Is it possible to use java hashmap in JNI exactly same as in java

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I know how to call Java classes in JNI and use it, so i call hashmap as same as other classes of Java.
But when I call put function of hashmap my code crashed.

```
jclass mapClass = env->FindClass("java/util/HashMap");
jclass myclass = env->FindClass("com/sample/source/market/PlaceOfMarket");
if (myclass != nullptr)
{
    LOG(INFO) << "myclass found";
} else {
    LOG(INFO) << "myclass not found";
}
if (mapClass != nullptr)
{
    LOG(INFO) << "mapclass found";

    jmethodID init = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "<init>", "()V");
    if (init != nullptr)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "constructor found";
    }
    jobject hashMap = env->NewObject(mapClass, init);
    if (hashMap != nullptr)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "hashMap class object created";
    }
    jmethodID put = env->GetMethodID(mapClass, "put", "(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;");
    if (put != nullptr)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << put method found";
    }
    PlaceOfMarket pos = PlaceOfMarket(100, 30);
    std::list<PlaceOfMarket> val = std::list<PlaceOfMarket>();
    val.push_back(PlaceOfMarket(23,42));
    env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, pos, val);
}
```

And my code crashed on `env->CallObjectMethod(hashMap, put, pos, val);` when I put data into hashmap.

Comment: `PlaceOfMarket` is not a `jobject`. You can only call it with Java objects, not your own.

Comment: What does the `PlaceOfMarket` Java class look like? How is it related to the C++ class? You will need to call its constructor to get a `jobject`.

Comment: Thank you @user207421 . Problem solved. I create jobject of **PlaceOfMarket** class and then try to put in hashmap and succeed.
Yes. I did the same Botje.